# Weird issue with namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, using-statement

I'm trying to use the System.Drawing.Color namespace.  I'm not able to define it at the top of the class:

[image]

However, I can reference it within the class.  That is, I can use this line of code, and it works:

```
txtBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
```

... but I'd rather just be able to do this:

```
txtBox.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
```

If it's a matter of a missing reference/dll, why am I able to make reference to System.Drawing.Color in my code?

Comment: What kind of project is this?  And what framework is it targeting?

Comment: I have a strange issue going on.  It turns out that it works if I just type the using statement out at the top of the class, even though it's not in my Intellisense menu.

Comment: Sounds like have not added the reference. Using VS 2010 when the reference to System.Drawing has not been adding, I cannot see it in intellisense.

Comment: Also, intellisense doesn't work when I type "Color. ..." in the normal code portion.  Yet, the code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: I have also experienced this in past, then I restarted the project and VS and it was fixed for me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it isn't a namespace. `System.Drawing` is the namespace, and `Color` is a structure (`struct`).

EDIT: Additionally, I'd advise to use a product such as [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which can correct stuff like this almost automagically. ReSharper rules!

Comment: Drawing is missing from the intellisense dropdown. The problem is he didn't reference it or accidentally deleted it from the references.

Comment: I think my issue, when boiled-down, turned out to be a caching problem of some sort, more than anything else.  Thanks for the help @Roy Dictus, @Inuyasha, and @0A0D.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons I can think of why System.Drawing could be filtered in the usings dropdown:

1. it is already used  ( -- nah, probably not, but anyway)
2. you're in a ASP.NET Service:

> [Caution: Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing.Color is a struct.
Namespace is System.Drawing

Comment: It's actually a struct, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to: `System.Drawing` in your project `References`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to your references - somehow it is missing.

then you have to declare `using System.Drawing;` in the top portion of your C# code then you can call `Color.LightPink;`

Comment: If you look in the Intellisense dropdown, System.Drawing isn't showing up.

Comment: @Inuyasha: Intellisence is not showing `System.Drawing` coz it may already added, also see for `System.Data`

Comment: @Javed: That is wrong. I can still see it in my intellisense even after it has already been declared.